# Aurelia Hot Module Reloading with aspnetcore 2.0

Tags: aurelia, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I want to get HMR working.

I am using VS2017.  I have created an aspnetcore 2.0 project, then added the aurelia framework using the Aurelia cli using 0.31.1 which [now](http://blog.aurelia.io/2017/08/18/aurelia-cli-webpack-update/) supports WebPack 3. I follow the instructions to make add SpaServices and modify start.cs.

I then run the project with `dotnet run`, and open IE and browse to `http://localhost:5000`see the expected "Hello World" from Aurelia.

Now I want to see HMR in action.  So I edit app.ts to change `Hello World` to `Hello HMR`  I then save the file.  I expect to see the change updated in IE.  But it never automatically reloads.

However, if I click the refresh button the browser, the change then shows up in IE.

Is there some other thing I am supposed to be doing here to get HMR working?

When I save the changes, I see the app.{guid}.bundle.js updated on disk (a new file is created with a new guid.  So that much is working.  But how to get the browser to react to that change and refresh?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think our CLI webpack setup currently supports HMR. As I said, I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inspecting the cli code, to get it to work you should set `"hmr": true` in `aurelia.json` under `platform`.
and call `au run --hmr --watch`.

edit: it fails to update my html (although the console shows me that `hmr` is active by listing all the changes I make)

edit2: I think this works when you actually use more than 1 module.
changes in the `app.html` only were not reflected back to the browser.

Comment: This is now working for me. I follow your instruction above, and use Chrome (not IE).  The site loads as expected.  I then update App and save.  In the console window, it shows the update is applied without restarting Aurelia from scratch.  So the update is applied and is visible in a few seconds.